# How can I modify the Location selector for Sales Orders screen

Tags: acumatica

I have a request to add fields to a selector for Location on the Sales Order screen.  In standard Acumatica style, this is not a typical selector, but something I've never seen before:

```
[LocationID(typeof(Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>,
                   And<Location.isActive, Equal<True>,
                   And<MatchWithBranch<Location.cBranchID>>>>)
            ,DescriptionField = typeof(Location.descr)
            ,Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
```

The fields I need to add are Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip.  How would I add these fields to this cryptic selector called 'LocationID'?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
    [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(LocationIDAttribute))]
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Location.locationID, 
                               InnerJoin<Address, 
                                   On<Location.defAddressID, Equal<Address.addressID>>>,
                       Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>,
                       And<Location.isActive, Equal<True>,
                       And<MatchWithBranch<Location.cBranchID>>>>>)
                ,typeof(Location.locationCD)
                ,typeof(Address.addressLine1)
                ,typeof(Address.addressLine2)
                ,typeof(Address.city)
                ,typeof(Address.state)
                ,typeof(Address.postalCode)
                ,SubstituteKey = typeof(Location.locationCD)
                ,DescriptionField = typeof(Location.descr))]
    protected virtual void SOOrder_CustomerLocationID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is a little tricky because the ability to change the column list is protected. We can change the columns by making our own location ID attribute that inherits the one we need to change and then replace the Dimension selector which at that time we can add the columns to be displayed. We also need to join in the address table to display the fields you are looking to add as they are not in the Location DAC.

Here are working examples:

A new attribute which we will use to replace the current attribute on SOOrder CustomerLocaitonID

```
public class LocationIDExtensionAttribute : LocationIDAttribute
{
    public LocationIDExtensionAttribute(params Type[] fieldList)
        : this(typeof(Where<boolTrue, Equal<boolTrue>>), fieldList)
    {
    }

    public LocationIDExtensionAttribute(Type WhereType, params Type[] fieldList)
        : base(WhereType)
    {
        AddColumns(WhereType, fieldList);
    }

    public LocationIDExtensionAttribute(Type WhereType, Type JoinType, params Type[] fieldList)
        : base(WhereType, JoinType)
    {
        AddColumns(WhereType, JoinType, fieldList);
    }

    protected void AddColumns(Type WhereType, params Type[] fieldList)
    {
        var dimensionSelector = _Attributes[_SelAttrIndex];
        if (dimensionSelector == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _Attributes[_SelAttrIndex] = (PXEventSubscriberAttribute)new PXDimensionSelectorAttribute("LOCATION", BqlCommand.Compose(typeof(Search<,>), typeof(Location.locationID), WhereType), typeof(Location.locationCD), fieldList);
    }

    protected void AddColumns(Type WhereType, Type JoinType, System.Type[] fieldList)
    {
        var dimensionSelector = _Attributes[_SelAttrIndex];
        if (dimensionSelector == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _Attributes[_SelAttrIndex] = (PXEventSubscriberAttribute)new PXDimensionSelectorAttribute("LOCATION", BqlCommand.Compose(typeof(Search2<,,>), typeof(Location.locationID), JoinType, WhereType), typeof(Location.locationCD), fieldList);
    }
}
```

Then we would use this attribute like this:

```
[LocationIDExtension(typeof(Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>,
        And<Location.isActive, Equal<True>,
            And<MatchWithBranch<Location.cBranchID>>>>),
    typeof(LeftJoin<Address, On<Location.defAddressID, Equal<Address.addressID>>>), 
    typeof(Location.locationCD),
    typeof(Location.descr), 
    typeof(Address.addressLine1), 
    typeof(Address.addressLine2), 
    typeof(Address.city),
    typeof(Address.state), 
    typeof(Address.postalCode), 
    DescriptionField = typeof(Location.descr),
    Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
```

And we end up with this:

[image]

Comment: That is absolutely awesome - worked perfectly!  Thanks so much, Brendan. ;D